# failed to start login service with Centos 7/6.iso through IMPI

Tags: linux, centos

As I made a mistake of the libc.so.6, I want to login to the rescue mode to solve it.
Currently, I'm using IMPI and get the virtual iso image. However, after I type F11, it shows many failures as the figure below. I also tried different version of CentOS 7 or 6.iso. However, this issue still exists. I appreciate if anyone could provide some suggestions to solve this issue.
Thank you for your time for reading this!

[image]

Comment: The message tells you right away: use `systemctl status systemd-logind`. If you can’t log in after booting normally, try booting in single-user/recovery mode (`single` on the kernel command line) and look at `journalctl -u systemd-logind --since yesterday`.

Comment: Thank you @user3840170 for giving me some suggestions. I have a stupid question.. as I cannot remote access to the server, do you know how to type "systemctl status systemd-logind" command ? I tried using the virtual keyboard through IMPI but it does not show anything....

Comment: If you can’t get IPMI to work with a keyboard, it’s unlikely any solution will work using IPMI. You should try to figure out why that isn’t working.

Comment: Thank you @jsbillings very much for your answer. I've called helps to solve it locally.